# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in MultiDex Android application

Tags: java, android, android-multidex

I am developing an Android app with large ammount of methods and with lot's of external libraries. And now my app is crashing with these exceptions

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, java.lang.Error: Failed to
 initialize JAXP 1.3 DatatypeFactory class and
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
 "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl" on path:
```

I was looking for the solution of these problems for a week but still have no succes. Can you help me please. In build.gradle file I have these lines

```
multiDexEnabled true,
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0',
 javaMaxHeapSize "4g",
my Application class extends MultiDexApplication
```

and I have added this line MultiDex.install(base); to the method  void attachBaseContext So i did everything according to google documentation and have no idea why i am getting this exception.

Comment: If you added MultiDex.install(base) you dont need to extend MultiDexApplication.

Comment: BTW do you have incremental true? if so - try to remove it.

Comment: no i have no incremental true. I'll change my application class code and remove extends MultiDexApplication

Comment: Still have the same error. These classes are not directly in my project but in the project that i am using as a library. May be i need to add all these lines int this library project, not only in my main project?